# Como armazenar uma palavra dentro de um vetor com tamanho maior que a palavra

Tags: c, array, microcontrolador

Declarei uma variável `char SendDataCmd[256]` que irá armazenar os comandos enviados do computador para o microcontrolador via `UART`. Os comandos tem tamanhos diferentes como por exemplo `RST, ADV ON e SET SNAME=BC118` entre outros. 
Tenho uma função que ira enviar os comandos, segue abaixo.

```
#include "bc118.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "main.h"

 char SendDataCmd[256];

int BC118_Init()
{
    SendDataCmd[] = "RST";//Linha que não funciona

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &SendDataCmd, 1, 100);

    SendDataCmd[] = "ADV ON";//Linha que não funciona

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, &SendDataCmd, 1, 100);



}
```

Estou com problema em armazenar os comandos dentro de `SendDataCmd` visto que eles tem tamanho diferente do vetor declarado, como poderia armazená-los de forma correta dentro desse vetor?

Comment: Quer copiar o texto para dentro do `SendDataCmd` ? Se for o caso a função que está a procura é [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)

Answer (score 0):

Não conheço código para microcontroladores, mas o código que você deu não compila. O erro está nas linhas que você marcou:

```
SendDataCmd[] = "blablabla";
```

Não é assim que se atribui strings em C. Primeiramente, o `[]` não faz parte do nome da variável, então não tem porquê ele aparecer do lado esquerdo do `=`.

Depois, mesmo que você fizesse a atribuição dessa forma, teria que declarar `SendDataCmd` como ponteiro e não como array.

Variáveis globais são ruins e odiosas. A sua variável `huart1` ser global até que vá lá, desde que você nunca queira interagir com duas delas. Mas esse `SendDataCmd` não tem nenhuma necessidade de ser global.

Se a função `BC118_Init` não devolve nenhum valor com qualquer significância, então ela deveria ser `void` ao invés de `int`.

Pelo que pesquisei, o terceiro parâmetro de `HAL_UART_Transmit` deveria ser o tamanho do comando, então usar o valor 1 fixo não vai funcionar.

O comando a ser passado no segundo parâmetro é do tipo `char *`, então você deve passar a string diretamente ao invés do endereço dela.

Talvez o que você queira seja isso:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "bc118.h"
#include "usart.h"
#include "main.h"

void transmitir(char *comando) {
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, comando, strlen(comando), 100);
}

void BC118_Init() {
    transmitir("RST");
    transmitir("ADV ON");
}
```